# alarmManager not properly set after restart

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to get a notification every day (at 13:00) with `alarmManager`, but when the device is restarted, the alarm is active for one day only and does not work for 2nd or 3rd day unless I run my application.

Why does it run only once?

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   alarmKurulum();
}



public void alarmKurulum() {
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 05);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    if(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis() < now.getTimeInMillis()) {
        alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000);
    }

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

AlarmReceiver.class:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        context.startService(service1); 
    }
}
```

TurnonAlarm.class (for reboot device)

```
public class TurnOnAlarmReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();

            alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
            alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 05);
            alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
            alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);


            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

            if(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis() < now.getTimeInMillis()) {
                alarmStartTime.setTimeInMillis(alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis() + 86400000);
            }
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);         
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ferhengakurdi9865"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >


        <service android:name=".AlarmService" />                
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".TurnOnAlarmReceive"  android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it easier for others to understand it and edited the title to better summarize your problem. I also formatted your code - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please also edit your code to make it compilable. Good luck!